# Oracle OCCI 'select count(*)' result fetching

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, occi

How can I get there results of the query execution - `select count (*) from myTable`?
The code is:

```
... 
oc::Statement* stmt = 
    m_cConnection->createStatement(select count (*) from myTable);

oc::ResultSet* res = stmt->executeQuery();
...
```

How can I get the value of the row count in `res`?

Comment: This feels like something you should be able to figure out from their documentation... Did you try something specific and have problems? (Also, you probably want that query in "s).

Comment: Do you have quotes around your select query in the source?

Comment: Found it! -     res->next();
    int nCount = res->getInt (1);

Answer (score 1):

Just write

```
cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
```

or

```
cout << "\t... MySQL counts: " << res->getInt(1) << endl;
```